# Django jinja does not see inherited templates

Tags: django, jinja2

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема.
Django jinja не видит дочерние шаблоны, не могу подключить их.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% load static %}
    <link type="text/css" href="{% static 'discount/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body >
```

title.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Во-первых, это не jinja. Во-вторых, что значит "не видит" и "не могу"? В чём конкретная проблема?

Comment: При запуске сервера <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title> показывает 127.0.0.1 а должен Title. Я подключаю в базовый шаблон (base.html)  дочерний шаблон title.html и это не работает

Comment: В показанных здесь шаблонах никакой 127.0.0.1 в принципе никак не может появиться, значит вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: Если в html  в тег <title></title>(вкладка сайта) при запуске сервера ничего не указать он показывает 127.0.0.1 Если явно передать <title>Title</title> то на вкладке сайта будет Tite, в моем случае я передаю данные в <title></title> через дочерний шаблон, и я не могу понять почему не работает.

Comment: В шаблоне base.html указан <title> пустой. В шаблоне title.html в <title> записывается Title. Никакой 127.0.0.1 здесь не может появиться вообще никак

Comment: Если вы смотрите не на <title>, а на название вкладки в браузере, то никто ж не обещал, что название вкладки будет совпадать с содержимым <title>, так что не надо вводить нас в заблуждение, рассказывая про неведомый 127.0.0.1 из названия вкладки

Comment: Где и как вы пытаетесь использовать дочерний шаблон?

Comment: Давайте по другому, я к базовому шаблону подключаю шапку сайта с навигацией из дочернего шаблона - и он не работает, не отображается
<body >
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            {% block header %}

            {% endblock %}
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Вопрос всё тот же — где и как вы пытаетесь использовать дочерний шаблон?

Comment: В django в папке templates у меня два шаблона это base.html (базовый) и header.html (дочерний, там шапка сайта) который я подключаю в base.html и при запуске сервера он не отображается

Comment: «который я подключаю в base.html» — в показанном вами шаблоне base.html нет никаких упоминаний других шаблонов. В показанном вами шаблоне из предыдущего комментария тоже нет никаких подключений шаблонов

Comment: Я делаю все как в документации Jinja в разделе Наследование шаблонов но у меня это не работает, почему понять не могу

Comment: Во-первых, повторяю ещё раз — **это не Jinja**. Во-вторых, вопрос всё тот же — где и как вы используете дочерние шаблоны? Пока что из ваших слов следует, что никак